# PHP while loop array data dispay into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

So I am making Text based browser game. I have made map where you can move around without refreshing page and updating it with javascript. I have added that it randomly generates bots from database which you can attack, but can't find a way to make it update when you move around the map.

This is the PHP I made to load the bots from database and make then randomly generate.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE botworld='$world'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
$row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$rowsbot = array();
while ($rowbot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) { 
     $rowsbot[] = $rowbot; 
} 
for($i=0;$i<count($rowsbot);$i++) { 
    $a = rand(0,10);
    if($a > 5) {
        echo "<div class='botres$i'>";
        echo "<div class='panel panel-default bot$i'><div class='panel-body bot1$i'>";
        echo $i . ". " . $rowsbot[$i]['name'];
        echo "<div class='pull-right'><button class='btn btn-default' botid='" . $rowsbot[$i]['id'] ."' botnr='" . $i . "'>Attack</button></div>";
        echo "</div></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

I added then it automaticly updates the div block when you attack bot. But I want to make bots update when you move around.

I have got the array with data, but don't know how to use it.

```
var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php print json_encode($row3); ?>');
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Could you say more about what you mean by "update when you move around the map?" Do you just mean that you want them to remain in a fixed position relative to the map while their position relative to yours changes? Or is it that you want them to navigate the map by doing a random walk or something?

Comment: what you want is call a javascript function and make a ajax request to update the row in the database?
Post your javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done

```
var rowsbot = <?php echo json_encode($rowsbot) ?>;
for(i=0; i<rowsbot.length; i++) {

var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
if(a>5) {
   $(".monsters").append("<div class='botres" + i + "'><div class='panel panel-default bot" + i + "'><div class='panel-body bot1 " + i + "'>" + i + ". " + rowsbot[i].name + "<div class='pull-right'><button class='btn btn-default' botid='" + rowsbot[i].id + "' botnr='" + i + "'>Attack</button></div></div></div></div>");
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you accept your answer MrEnergy so that we know you've solved your problem :) .